Alinear icono con texto en NavMenu
Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi componente NavMenu.razor.
La idea es que los iconos salgan alineados con sus correspondientes textos.
Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?
Gracias
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
            <img src="imagenes/propiedad1.png" class="img-fluid" width="40" />
            Propiedades</a>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" />

<div class="nav-scrollable" onclick="document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler').click()">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <i class="bi bi-house-door-fill" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"></i>&nbsp; Inicio
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="auth">
                <i class="bi bi-bookmark-plus-fill" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"></i>&nbsp; Categorías
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

La imagen me sale asi:


Supongo que podrás agregar código CSS a mano, capaz puedes darle la propiedad display:flex, align-items:center; a nav-link.

Disculpa, pero soy nuevo en esto. Dómde iríaexactamente la propiedad que mencionas? La pongo así pero sigue igual. Gracias  

@MarioEscudero aplica el style al 'nav-item' además de encerrar 'Inicio' y 'Categoría' en un span.

Prueba esto usando flex. Los elementos dentro del DIV con style="display: flex; align-items: center;" se alinearán al centro verticalmente.


<div class="nav-scrollable" onclick="document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler').click()">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
               <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                  <i class="bi bi-house-door-fill" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"></i>&nbsp; Inicio
                </div>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="auth">
             <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                <i class="bi bi-bookmark-plus-fill" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"></i>&nbsp; Categorías
             </div>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>



